# How to fix jumping upon clicking search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I've tried to add a simple search controller but whenever I'm clicking on it so it becomes active, it jumps up, out of screen. Why is that even happening? I checked all the code and I'm not manipulating with constraints or anything.

I initialize my search controller through the following function (and call it in ViewDidLoad):

```
private func initSearchController() {
    self.searchController = ({
        let controller =     UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        return controller
    })()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Did you try `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

Comment: Actually, I ended up with that. Still, let's say it was not satisfactory because initially, I wanted my nav nar to be trumped by search bar. Basically this:
1) search bar becomes active
2) nav bar hides itself
3) search bar goes in place of nav bar
4) on cancel everything goes back to its place
At least, I saw this animation in most solutions and for me it was the best

Comment: If you found my answer useful could you please check it is true answer?

Comment: @matt no, search controller shouldn't disappear out of nowhere

Answer (score 0):

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```